# How can I get the share point URL in mapping driver

Tags: python, sharepoint

share point site can be linked by on-premise to local file browser. like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw2MZ.png)

what I want to know is how to get the site url like : https://sites.inside-sharex.xxxx.com/sites/141475xxxx

by python code?

just like get the net mapping driver in coding :

```
import win32wnet
import sys

print(win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(r"S:\", 1))

# and I will get the real URL for this mapping driver.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "View online"?
[image]

It will open the folder/file in browser, then you can find the site url.

If I misunderstand your meaning, please feel free to reply.

Comment: yes! but it's manually way. I want to know how to tringle it automatic. it's on context menu and I think there may be a way can tringle it directly.